# How to extract adjacent pair of words in associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array in PHP like this:

```
$weight["a"]=1;
$weight["b"]=4;
$weight["c"]=5;
$weight["d"]=9;
```

Here I want to calculate pair-wise difference between consecutive array elements, e.g.,

```
"b-a" = 3
"c-b" = 1
"d-c" = 4
```

How should this be computed?

Comment: Really?  None of these help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($weight AS $curr) { 
      if ($i > 0) {
        echo '"'.array_keys($weight)[$i].'-'.array_keys($weight)[$i-1].'" = '.($curr-$prev)."<br />";    
      }
      $i++;
      $prev = $curr;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think dear that associative array is iterated as you coded `foreach ($weight AS $curr)` . This code is giving no output either.

Comment: The image is uploaded. Hope you don't need any more proof rt.

Comment: I am using old version of PHP. The above `array_keys` syntax only works in PHP ver. 5.4+ ... Got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Store keys on a temporary array where keys are integers on which you can easily get the next key, and use it to parse your main array.

```
$tmp_array = array();
foreach ($weight as $key => $val) {
    $tmp_array[] = $key;
}
$array_length = count($tmp_array);
for ($i = 0; i < array_length - 2; ++$i) {
    echo $weight[$tmp_array[$i+1]], '-', $weight[$tmp_array[$i]], ' = ', ($weight[$tmp_array[$i+1]] - $weight[$tmp_array[$i]], PHP_EOL;
}
```